# Military spaceship crew hoping to get their memories and bodies back after mission

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In the mid-1970s I read a story about a spaceship crewed by people (or one person) who had been incorporated into the ship (I think), and had most of their memories temporarily erased before the mission against "the enemy" - they had been promised that after the mission they would have their memories restored, and return to civilian life.  At the end of the story it becomes clear that

> the crew is being fooled - the enemy is the legitimate government of their home planet, and their last mission has destroyed the facility storing their memories.

I was reading a lot of Galaxy collections back then, so it might have appeared in one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[City of Yesterday](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54238) by Terry Carr (I remembered reading [Beyond Control](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4304) and checked its table of contents - and even though the title didn't sound that familiar, the [Archived version](https://archive.org/details/1967-12_IF/page/n85/mode/2up) matched my memories.

This question is therefore a duplicate of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76377/short-story-about-a-pilot-who-is-integral-to-a-space-ship-that-attacks-planets/76384#76384), but I focused on different aspects than the previous questioner

**In the mid-1970s I read a story about a spaceship crewed by people (or one person) who had been incorporated into the ship (I think), and had most of their memories temporarily erased before the mission against "the enemy"**

> J-1001011 felt his heart speed up momentarily, before Chaiies’s
> nerve-implants detected and corrected it.
>
> When the Control machines had come for him he had been ten years old,
> old enough to know his own name, but they had erased it. They had had
> to clear his memory for the masses of minute data he’d need for
> service, so the machines had stored his personal memories in neat
> patterns of microenergy, waiting for his release.

**their last mission has destroyed the facility storing their memories.**

> "Who your parents were, on what planet they lived — all this
> information has been destroyed in the city on Rhinstruk. It was the
> archives center of the Galactic Federation, storing all the
> memory-data of our service humans. Useless information, since none of
> it will ever be used again — and potentially harmful, because the
> humans assigned to guard it were engaged in a plot to broadcast the
> data through official machine communications channels to the
> original holders of the memories. So it became necessary to destroy
> the city.”